# Clean/legible way to use a library method based on user input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a little library to convert an SVG I'm grabbing in a react app and convert it into a downloadable asset. The library exposes several methods like `.toPng()`, `.toSvg()`, or `.toJpg()` and spits out a base64 encoded string with the desired MIME type so you can download an asset easily.

I'm building a hook that will let me grab a user-selected file type so that the user can control what type of image they download. I'm trying to think of a succinct, legible way to dynamically select one of the library's exposed methods, working within the following setup:

```js
import { toPng, toJpeg, toSvg } from 'html-to-image'
import { useRef, useState } from 'react'

export default function useHtmlToImage() {
  const chartRef = useRef()
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)

  const getDownloadableImage = async imageFormat => {
    if (chartRef !== null && chartRef?.current?.container) {
      setIsLoading(true)

      return await htmlToImage
        .toSvg(chartRef.current.container)  // <-- Want to swap this method out based on UI
        .then(dataUrl => {
          return dataUrl
        })
    }
  }

  return [
    getDownloadableImage,
    {
      chartRef,
      isLoading
    }
  ]
}
```

So far I can verify that the user input is passed to my hook, but i'm at a loss on how I could dynamically swap the methods (seen at the top in the import statement) based on a user input.

Comment: Why not use a `switch case`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS functions are first-class objects. This means you can work with them like any other data, for example put them in data structures:

```
const conversions = { toPng, toJpeg, toSvg };
```

Which then can simply be indexed by value from user input:

```
<select value={selectedConversion}>
  <option value="toPng">PNG</option>
  <option value="toJpeg">JPEG</option>
  <option value="toSvg ">SVG</option>
</select>

const conversion = conversions[selectedConversion];
return await conversion(chartRef.current.container).then(u => u);
```

You can introduce anothers set of values that would serve as a mapping to a specific function - in that case, simply key the `conversions` object explicitly.

Comment: Ah thank you. I think that my brain was a bit scrambled and something like this had occurred to me but I didn't implement it correctly. This is legible and I think will work well in my use case!